# PowerPoint 2007 - Save images to a file?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I was sent some PowerPoint 2007 files with approximately 75 slides in each. On each slide is one photo.  I need to extract the photo from each slide to save in a folder on my system. How can it be achieved?

Comment: Take a look at the `ExtractPPTFile` subroutine [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19394355/1467082). You can ignore the first two subs in that answer. This would let you export all contents of the file, either as HTML or ZIP, in either case the output should I think include all of the image files contained in the Presentation.

Answer (score 2):

```
For Each Slide in ActivePresentation.Slides
    Slide.Shapes(1).Export FileName:="folderPath\imageName.jpg" _
        Filter:=ppShapeFormatJPG
Next Slide
```

Comment: This is a good place to start. OP may need to doe a bit more conditional logic if there are other `Shapes` in each slide, but this is the right method to use.  +1.

Comment: 100% agree. OP will also need to consider the file format and a process of changing the image name to prevent overwriting the saved image.

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you NEED to do the job using VBA, follow the link David's provided.

If it's a one-shot need to extract the images, make a copy of the PPTX file to begin with.
Let's call it COPY.PPTX for purposes of argument.
Rename COPY.PPTX to COPY.ZIP or even COPY.PPTX.ZIP

Now open the zip file, browse to the media folder and there you'll find the images in the file.  Drag them out to wherever you want to store them and you're done.

Comment: +1. For sharing the fact that the content if a `.PPTX` file is actually zipped! Fantastic.